# Meaning of "exposures" in relation to (currency) investment

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "In fact, it is Trump that poses the immediate risk to the GBP/USD rather than
>   Brexit talks," Razaqzada said. "Although the cable is weak at the time of this
>   writing, it could very easily bounce back as speculators reduce their long
>   **exposures** to the dollar ahead of Trump’s speech."

<sup>Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/pound-pushed-lower-as-scottish-referendum-worries-emerge-2017-02-27</sup>

Does it mean "interest", I wonder?

Comment: There it means "risky investment position" or "risky investment posture".

Comment: *Exposure* is financial shorthand for *exposure to risk* -- holding a "long" position in the dollar exposes the investor to the risk of loss if the value of the dollar falls.

Comment: @haile: The normal prepositions are **in** or **on**, not "**to** the dollar".